# Can't turn off autoclose tags in Adobe Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

I recently updated to brackets 1.8 and now I can't disable the auto close brackets.  I've got this in my Braskets.json file

```
"closeTags": 
{
    "dontCloseTags": [],
    "indentTags": [],
    "whenOpening": false,
    "whenClosing": false  
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised what the issue is.  I needed this line

```
    "closeBrackets": false,
```